# Function has more than 25 lines, how can I make it shorter C

Tags: c

I'm doing an exercise where I have to convert two-digit `int` values to `char`. I need to shorten the code to 25 lines or fewer. The goal of the exercises is to print all possible number combinations given two ints 00 00 using the `write()` function thus the need to convert it to `char`.

```
void    ft_print(int a, int b)
{
    char    a1;
    char    a2;
    char    b1;
    char    b2;

    if (a >= 10)
    {
        a1 = a / 10 + '0';
        a2 = a % 10 + '0';
    }
    else
    {
        a1 = '0';
        a2 = a + '0';
    }
    if (b >= 10)
    {
        b1 = b / 10 + '0';
        b2 = b % 10 + '0';
    }
    else
    {
        b1 = '0';
        b2 = b + '0';
    }  
    ft_putchar(a1, a2, b1, b2);
}
```

Comment: Since the logic for `a`'s is same for `b` 's I would put them both in an array of 2, and loop it.

Comment: You don't need neither the `if` checks nor the `else` blocks.

Comment: If you are concerned about the number of lines, a ternary can help: `a >= 10 ? (a1 = a / 10 + '0', a2 = a % 10 + '0') : (a1 = '0', a2 = a + '0');`

Comment: Excellent advice from the film "Amadeus": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCud8H7z7vU

Comment: There is no need for either of the `else` clauses; if `a < 10`, the `a / 10 + '0'` will be `'0'` (same for `b`)

Comment: If you don't like a one-liner (I don't blame you), you can use:
```char a1 = a / 10 + '0'; char a2 = a % 10 + '0'; char b1 = b / 10 + '0'; char b2 = b % 10 + '0'; ft_putchar(a1, a2, b1, b2);``` spread over 5 lines.  Avoid making special cases where there is no need to do so!  Note that if either input is not in the range 0..99, you will get erroneous output.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in one line:

```
void ft_print(int a, int b)
{
  ft_putchar((a / 10 + '0'), (a % 10 + '0'), (b / 10 + '0'), (b % 10 + '0'));
}
```

Comment: +1.  But the theory behind function line limits doesn't result in any improvement.  The number of lines it takes to write a function in a clear, understandable, maintainable matter is irrelevant.  What matters is it being clear, understandable, and maintainable.  And I'd argue cramming as many operations into as few lines as possible produces code that results in none of those.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If clarity was the OP's goal then the code he initially had was fine. Since he's looking for brevity it would seem that maintainability and clarity isn't his priority in this case.